# найти общие слова в двух текстах Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно сравнить два текста, найти в них общие слова и посчитать. Дан скелет программы: два текста открываются как один список, из которого надо сделать два словаря. Не могу понять, какие должны быть в них ключи и как разделить два текста на словари, если они открыты вместе.

```
# Collect the command line arguments
texts = sys.argv[1:3]
option = ''
# Check if a sorting option is given

# Create dictionaries of texts' words and put them into a list
dictionaries = []
for data in texts:
    words = {}

    # your code

    dictionaries.append(words)


# Looking for words that appear in both texts

# your  code


# Creating count dictionary for common words and their absolute count
common_words = {}

# Sorting dictionary
common_words_sorted = []
if "alpha" in option:
    print("Option 1") 

    # your code

elif "freq" in option:
    print("Option 2") 

    # your code
else:
    common_words_sorted = common_words
    print("No valid sorting option was chosen. Data was not sorted.")

print("words in common:")
for item in common_words_sorted:
    print("common words") 
    # your code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** (as per @Эникейщик) - я поздно сообразил, что в одном и том же тексте могут повторятся слова. Тогда подход, изложенный в задании имеет смысл и сводится к такому решению:

```
texts=['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit', 'dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit, amet ipsum amet']
dictionaries=[]
for data in texts:
    words={}
    for word in data.split():
        words[word] = words.get(word, 0) + 1
    dictionaries.append(words)

common = [x for x in dictionaries[0].keys() if x in dictionaries[1].keys()]
print(common)
```

Получим:

```
['ipsum', 'dolor', 'amet']
```

Либо:

```
common=dictionaries[0].keys() & dictionaries[1].keys()
print(common)
```

Получим:

```
{'amet', 'dolor', 'ipsum'}
```

Либо, раз уж по заданию нужно посчитать, то так:

```
common = {x:(dictionaries[0][x]+dictionaries[1][x]) for x in dictionaries[0].keys() if x in dictionaries[1].keys()}
print(common)
```

Получим:

```
{'ipsum': 3, 'dolor': 2, 'amet': 3}
```

*Советую только обратить внимание на разбиение текста на слова. простой `split()` будет включать в слова пунктуацию, что, скорее всего, вам помешает.*

**UPDATE 2** (после пояснения задания автором вопроса)

```
texts=['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit', 'dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit, amet ipsum amet']
dictionaries=[]
for data in texts:
    words={}
    for word in data.split():
        words[word] = words.get(word, 0) + 1
    dictionaries.append(words)

common = [x for x in dictionaries[0].keys() if x in dictionaries[1].keys()]

print("Words in common: ")
for key in common:
    print("{} - text1: {} text2: {}".format(key, dictionaries[0][key], 
dictionaries[1][key]))
```

На выходе:

```
Words in common: 
ipsum - text1: 1 text2: 2
dolor - text1: 1 text2: 1
amet - text1: 1 text2: 2
```

Comment: По второму варианту - что будет, если в одном тексте слово встречается больше одного раза, а в другом ни разу?

Comment: @Эникейщик Я уже сообразил, что может быть такой вариант, не успел еще правку внести

Comment: Результат должен выглядеть так:  words in common:
. –– text1: 18 text2: 19    the –– text1: 36 text2: 18, поэтому я решил, что данные надо брать из разных словарей. Извините, если вопрос глупый. Я только начал учить язык

Comment: @total_rookie Не стоит извиняться. На будущее лучше сразу все пояснения в теле вопроса указывать (в том числе и то, каким вы хотите видеть результат). Я дополнил ответ. Надеюсь, это то, что вам нужно.